# Spring with jersey and oauth security giving 404: Not Found error for REST API

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jersey-client

I am implementing OAuth2 with spring, getting access_token but when i call Rest API along with access_token it gives 404: Not Found error.

Web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    Restful Web Application

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring-context.xml</param-value>
    <param-value>classpath:spring-security-oauth2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.dpdocter.webservices;com.dpdocter.beans</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

spring-secuirty-oauth2.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
        parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<http pattern="/api/**" create-session="stateless"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>


<!-- This is simple authentication manager, with a hardcoded user/password 
    combination. We can replace this with a user defined service to get few users 
    credentials from DB -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="java" password="java" authorities="ROLE_APP" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>


<!-- This defined token store, we have used inmemory tokenstore for now 
    but this can be changed to a user defined one -->
<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

<!-- This is where we defined token based configurations, token validity 
    and other things -->
<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="12000000" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
</bean>

<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
    resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <!-- client -->
    <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
        authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
        authorities="ROLE_APP" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />

    <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
        authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,password,refresh_token,implicit"
        secret="restapp" scope="read,write,trust" authorities="ROLE_APP" />

</oauth:client-details-service>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

Here **/api/**** is path for my REST API.

Getting Token :

http://localhost:8080/myapp/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=restapp&client_secret=restapp&username=java&password=java

Response : {"access_token":"21e165a4-0df9-4452-9e1e-491025b6cf9b","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"e5afd74f-5e28-4879-b066-e672fade2ec3","expires_in":11999999,"scope":"read trust write"}

But when calling API

http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/getList?access_token=21e165a4-0df9-4452-9e1e-491025b6cf9b

Gives 404 Not found error